# 'onCreate(Bundle)' is already defined in activity

Tags: android

Being my first project ever and wanting to implement banner ads in my app, I don't know how to get rid of this problem: `'onCreate(Bundle)' is already defined in activity` in MainActity.java .
Here's the problematic part:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private AdView mAdView;

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        MobileAds.initialize(this, new OnInitializationCompleteListener() {
            @Override
            public void onInitializationComplete(InitializationStatus initializationStatus) {
            }
        });

        mAdView = findViewById(R.id.adView);
        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
        mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);



    }

    private WebView webView;

    @SuppressLint("SetJavaScriptEnabled")
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        CustomWebViewClient client = new CustomWebViewClient(this);
        webView = findViewById(R.id.webView);
        webView.setWebViewClient(client);
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.clearCache(true);
        webView.loadUrl("https://example.com/");
    }
```

Comment: You have two identical `onCreate` methods in that `Activity`. When the system calls `onCreate` which one is it meant to run? If you want all that code to run, combine them into one method (and don't duplicate the common lines, i.e. the `super` call and the `setContentView` one)

Comment: (you can't have two functions with the same signature anyway - same name, same parameter types in the same order - but the point is you probably want all that stuff in the same place, running together, right?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are declaring the same method twice. Just add the content of the second method in the first method and delete the second. Like so:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private AdView mAdView;
    private WebView webView;

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        MobileAds.initialize(this, new OnInitializationCompleteListener() {
            @Override
            public void onInitializationComplete(InitializationStatus initializationStatus) {
            }
        });

        mAdView = findViewById(R.id.adView);
        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
        mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);
        CustomWebViewClient client = new CustomWebViewClient(this);
        webView = findViewById(R.id.webView);
        webView.setWebViewClient(client);
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.clearCache(true);
        webView.loadUrl("https://example.com/");

    }
}
```